# terminate a handler execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, handler

I need to terminate a handler execution in JavaScript in order to allow methods/handlers to be executed in a Web page. For example, the following piece of code illustrates what I need:

```
function handler() {
    //doing many things 1
    internalProcess() 
    //doing many things 2 (it is not executed)
} 

function internalProcess() {
    //doing many things 3
    //terminate the handler execution
}
```

I have seen some solutions using `throw` but they are not working for me because sometimes other functions in the handler captures this exception and the handler continues its execution.

Comment: `throw`, is the correct way.   `sometimes other functions in the handler captures this exception` then maybe they should not.  It's hard to tell without a more concrete example.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.... If they catch the errors, not sure what you can do....

Comment: Could just add a `return;` after `internalProcess()` in the first handler?

Comment: There is no mechanism that directly does what you're asking; `throw` is about as close as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

`throw` would be appropriate if you are handling errors in your `internalProcess`. You would simply need to [`try / catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) in you handler:

```js
function handler() {
  try {
    console.log('doing many things 1');
    internalProcess();
    console.log('doing many things 2');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('interrupted:', e.message);
  }
} 

function internalProcess() {
    console.log('doing many things 3');
    //terminate the handler execution
    throw new Error('a message');
}

handler();
```

If you just want to sometimes stop execution of `handler()` depending on computations that happen in `internalProcess()`, here's a way without using throw:

Simply make the return value of `internalProcess()` tell `handler()` whether to continue running or not:

```js
function handler() {
    console.log('doing many things 1');
    const shouldContinue = internalProcess();
    if (!shouldContinue) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('doing many things 2');
} 

function internalProcess() {
    console.log('doing many things 3');
    //terminate the handler execution
    return false;
}

handler();
```

Comment: `} catch (e) {` you really need to be sure this is what you want,.  eg.  the function handler will now always succeed, as you don't re-throw.   Generally speaking exception handling is something that's handled right at the root of your application,.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think it really depends on your needs, I'm not sure what the use case is here, which is why I recommend the second option. There are definitely use cases where you want to handle known exceptions, for example on an event handler since there is no other function directly calling it. In this example, I assumed `handler` was an event handler, and wanted to do error handling within it, but yes, if you want to expose errors to users you would need to rethrow.

Comment: The second solution doesn't work for me, because I have to interrupt an execution. 

My only problem with the first one if the call of `internalProcess` (which triggers the exception) is inside of another function, `foo`, that captures this exception because `foo` uses  `catch(e)`.  Maybe If creates a particular object exception, it is not captured.

Comment: I see... you should try posting a [mcve], that would help us understand the specifics of your problem and provide better answers.